# Detect missing object using image comparison

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have an app that needs to take two photos of a room and detect if one of the objects in the first photos is missing in the second photo. How can it do it using OpenCV or any other tool?

Comment: This is harder than you think.

Comment: Do both images have the same POV ? Do you have a template of the object you'll be looking for ? Will the object always have the same orientation ? Or are you just looking for any/all missing objects ?
I think will have to elaborate more on your problem if you want a more complete answer.

Comment: Calculate the Diff of two frames, provided the camera position and illumination remains same, it would yield you a binary mask which you can later use to find contours and get the location of missing object

Comment: @Soltius Thanks for the quick reply
1. Both photos are taken separately by a regular user with a smartphone so the angle and the orientation will not be exactly the same.
2. I do not have template of the missing object
3. We can assume that only one object will be missing and it is located more or less in the center of the image.

Comment: OK, so one way would be :

a/ image registration (finding the transformation such that both images are overlayed) (might need to include warping)

b/ image subtraction to find the difference between the image.


What's difficult is that registration might not be perfect so you'll have a lot of differences in b/ if your overlayed images are shifted even a little bit, but maybe you'll have one "big difference" at your missing object's location and you'll be able to locate it with post - processing.

Comment: @Soltius is there a way to do it with opencv? Could you direct me how to do steps A and B using opencv? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your object of interest has well known structure - i.e. it's an augmented reality marker, then this task is well described and almost trivial to implement. If you don't have a priori knowledge about the missing object, the only thing you can do is to compare 2 photos i.e. like in panorama stitching which can be done with SIFT or SURF (please read further about these). If the object is more complicated and if both the images were taken with similar field of view and the model of the missing object is known a priori (i.e. you have a picture of the object of interest and ONLY it), you can use SIFT or SURF to detect features both in the a priori model image and in the input image (the one where you want to find the missing object), perform feature matching and look for the densest cluster of matching features (i.e. use particle swarm optimization algorithm). You need to be aware that this won't work in every case and might give you quite a lot of false-positives. Disturbances such as the object looking different from every side, differences in lighting, partial occlusions etc will easily break this model. This approach does not require dewarping of the image etc. since SIFT is scale, translation and rotation invariant.

There are plenty of more robust methods for this, including deep learning (look for scientific papers on object detection), but the one with feature matching seems to be the easiest thing to try first.